# How to split a sql table into two tables using a third table containing reference values

Tags: sql-server

I am new here and new to sql therefore I hope I am asking the the question correct.

table internal product EAN

```
EAN/UPC 
1234567789 
2233445566
```

table shop sales

```
EAN/UPC    | product | sales value |
1234567789 | xyz     | 200         |
2233445566 | abc     | 100         |
9685444444 | yyy     | 150         |
```

Result should look like:

table my company sales

```
EAN/UPC    | product | sales value |
1234567789 | xyz     | 200         |
2233445566 | abc     | 100         |
```

and

table my competitor sales

```
EAN/UPC    | product | sales value |
9685444444 | yyy     | 150         |
```

I have all my EAN/UPC codes available (about 100.000)
I am receiving the sales data from the shop including competitor EAN/UPC codes which I need to seperate from mine. I would like to use the first table as reference and if move the values where the EAN/UPC match into the table my company sales, the others where there is no matching EAN/UPC into the table my competitors sales.

I was thinking about using a select into statement with the condition where EAN/UPC T1 is not EAN/UPC T2  .

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try your sql, and share with us what you see.  Creating two new tables is one way>> another way is to create two VIEWs having either IN Product tbl or Not IN Product table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
into CompanySales
from ShopSales
where [EAN/UPC] in (select [EAN/UPC] from productEAN);

Select * 
into CompetitorSales
from ShopSales
where [EAN/UPC] not in (select [EAN/UPC] from productEAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work out:

Setup (for testing purposes) using CTE:

```
WITH [shop sales] ([EAN/UPC], [product], [sales value]) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            (1234567789,'xyz',200), 
            (2233445566,'abc',100), 
            (9685444444,'yyy',150)
    ) AS A (Column1, Column2, Column3)
),
[internal product EAN] ([EAN/UPC]) AS ( 
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            (1234567789), 
            (2233445566)
    ) AS A (Column1)
)
```

Two queries to pull the information:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM [internal product EAN] ip
INNER JOIN [shop sales] s ON ip.[EAN/UPC] = s.[EAN/UPC]

SELECT s.*
FROM [shop sales] s
WHERE s.[EAN/UPC] NOT IN (SELECT [EAN/UPC] FROM [internal product EAN])
```

As far as creating tables from the data, an `INSERT INTO` or a `SELECT INTO` for a new table would probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO OnlyMyProductSales([EAN],[product],SalesValue)
SELECT s.*
FROM [MyProduct] p
INNER JOIN [AllSales] s 
    ON p.[EAN] = s.[EAN]

INSERT INTO MyCompetitionSales([EAN],[product],SalesValue)
SELECT s.*
FROM  [AllSales] s
    LEFT JOIN [MyProduct] p 
        ON p.[EAN] = s.[EAN]
WHERE s.[EAN] IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

this will help:

```
CREATE TABLE #internalproductEAN (EAN_UPC  VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #internalproductEAN
SELECT 1234567789 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2233445566


CREATE TABLE #shopsales (EAN_UPC  VARCHAR(50),product VARCHAR(10),SalesValue BIGINT)
INSERT INTO #shopsales
SELECT '1234567789','xyz',200  UNION ALL
SELECT '2233445566','abc',100  UNION ALL
SELECT '9685444444','yyy',150 

CREATE TABLE #companysales (EAN_UPC  VARCHAR(50),product VARCHAR(10),SalesValue BIGINT)


INSERT INTO #companysales
SELECT ss.* FROM #shopsales ss
INNER JOIN #internalproductEAN ip ON ss.EAN_UPC=ip.EAN_UPC

SELECT * FROM #companysales

CREATE TABLE #competitorsales (EAN_UPC  VARCHAR(50),product VARCHAR(10),SalesValue BIGINT)

INSERT INTO #competitorsales
SELECT ss.* FROM #shopsales ss
LEFT JOIN #internalproductEAN ip ON ss.EAN_UPC=ip.EAN_UPC
WHERE ip.EAN_UPC IS NULL

SELECT * FROM #competitorsales


--SELECT * FROM #internalproductEAN
--SELECT * FROM #shopsales

DROP TABLE #internalproductEAN
DROP TABLE #shopsales
DROP TABLE #companysales
DROP TABLE #competitorsales
```